# React native rn-fetch-blob download issue

Tags: javascript, react-native, react-native-fs, react-native-fetch-blob, rn-fetch-blob

In react native library rn fetch blob i want to fetch data from api and save. The problem i am facing is that i want to save the file from api only after downloading complete. And if downloading cancelled there is no file to be stored . Is there any solution for this . Thanks all

Comment: is it possible to catch the error, and use react-native-fs to delete the unfinished file?

Comment: There is an option to delete manually like react native fs. So no need of another package to delete it . my doubt is when deletion cancelled in middle of downloading, there should ne no file